# Jquery length not working with elements with variable in name

Tags: jquery, variables

It works if you put only `$('li').lenght;`

length is not working if you add a variable to the name `$('#id_'+variable).length;`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("button").click(function() {
                    var tu = '1';
                    alert($("#uno_" + tu).length);
                    // IT WORKS IF YOU PUT ONLY $('li').lenght;
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <button>Alert the number of li elements</button>
        <ul>
            <li id="uno_1">Coffee</li>
            <li id="uno_1">Milk</li>
            <li id="uno_1">Soda</li>
        </ul>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: **ID should always be unique** `use class instead` like `class='uno_1'` then in jquery `$(".uno_"+tu).length`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kks320w0/ it works, check the order of your js

Comment: THANKS THAT WORKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Id can not be duplicated in html, Id should be unique for each element in the page, but you can use class here instead of Id.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("button").click(function(){
      var tu = '1';
      alert($(".uno_"+tu).length);
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Alert the number of li elements</button>

<ul>
  <li class="uno_1">Coffee</li>
  <li class="uno_1">Milk</li>
  <li class="uno_1">Soda</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("button").click(function(){
    var tu = 1;
                alert($("#uno_"+tu).html().length);

            });
        });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <button>Alert the number of li elements</button>

    <ul>
      <li id="uno_1">phpsiliguri.com</li>
      <li id="uno_2">google.com</li>
      <li id="uno_3">yahoo.com</li>
    </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```